# How can I reposition the Floating Button in Codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

The FloatingButton seems to be added only in Form.getContentPane() and cannot be added to a container
Adding it to my form would make the button shield some components underneaths,

Any solution to this? I would like to have positioned inside the scrolling table in a BorderLayout.CENTER

not much options here:

```
fab.bindFabToContainer(current, Component.RIGHT, Component.CENTER);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
fab.bindFabToContainer(current, Component.RIGHT, Component.CENTER);
```

Doesn't add the fab to a container. It creates a new container and returns it so the right statement would be:

```
current = fab.bindFabToContainer(current, Component.RIGHT, Component.CENTER);
myForm.add(current);
```

Since the fab needs to float on top and we don't want to change your existing layout we create a new wrapper container with layered layout.

Notice that in the form/content page we can use the existing form layered layout (plus the content pane can't be replaced) so we detect that and use a special case with the layered pane.

Comment: I really did not understand, my statement has "current" as the Form, and button is adder as depicted in the picture position in SOUTH_EAST of frame above the BorderLayout.SOUTH, how can I add the fab on the SOUTH_EAST of the BorderLayout.CENTER, ? without using the return value fo the fab creation method

Comment: So instead of using current in my code just use table and assign the return value to `tableReplacement` then instead of adding table to the form add `tableReplacement`. I'm not sure how well it will handle the scrollability though. The core idea is that this is supposed to "float".