# CodenameOne Floating Action Button binding error

Tags: java, codenameone, floating-action-button, master-detail

My CodenameOne app has a master/detail layout with special size constraints.
Also a "plus" button is present to allow creation of new items.

In the main form:

```
FloatingActionButton fab=FloatingActionButton.createFAB(FontImage.MATERIAL_ADD);
...

if(isTablet() && !isPortrait())
    {
        mainForm.add(tl.createConstraint().heightPercentage(100).widthPercentage((int)(leftContainerRatio*100)),masterContainer)
                .add( mainEditingContainer);
        fab.bindFabToContainer(masterContainer); //error here
    } else {
        mainForm.add(masterContainer);
        fab.bindFabToContainer(masterContainer);
    }
```

When running it I get:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component is already contained in Container: Container[x=0 y=20 width=2048 height=1514 name=null, layout = TableLayout, scrollableX = false, scrollableY = false, components = [masterContainer, Container]]
at com.codename1.ui.Container.insertComponentAtImpl(Container.java:927)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.insertComponentAt(Container.java:918)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.addComponent(Container.java:840)
at com.codename1.ui.Container.encloseIn(Container.java:250)
at com.codename1.ui.layouts.LayeredLayout.encloseIn(LayeredLayout.java:1099)
at com.codename1.components.FloatingActionButton.bindFabToContainer(FloatingActionButton.java:314)
at com.codename1.components.FloatingActionButton.bindFabToContainer(FloatingActionButton.java:286)
at com.myapp.app.MyApp.start(MyApp.java:186)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$3$1.run(Executor.java:258)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1331)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:1125)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

but nowhere the FAB is added or bound, other where shown in code snippet.

If the bind method is removed no button appears.

(The app is running in the simulator)

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

See this to understand what happened: [How can I reposition the Floating Button in Codenameone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63763608/how-can-i-reposition-the-floating-button-in-codenameone)

The gist of it is that when you use `FloatingActionButton` on a non-form container you need to add its result. Since the container you gave is now wrapped.

So your code should be:

```java
if(isTablet() && !isPortrait()) {
   mainForm.add(tl.cc().hp(100).wp((int)(leftContainerRatio*100)), 
                        fab.bindFabToContainer(MasterContainer))
           .add( mainEditingContainer);
} else {
    mainForm.add(fab.bindFabToContainer(MasterContainer));
}
```

Comment: It works, but in portrait mode I have mainForm.add(fab.bindFabToContainer(masterContainer)); and with this the same error is issued (it's at startup, not rotating)

Comment: Did you apply my change to the else statement too?

Comment: Is MasterContainer added to something in some other location before this line. This exception is thrown if a user already has a parent and you try to add it. You can step over the code with the debugger and see the parent property